# typeahead.js Bloodhound initialize and clear not working

Tags: javascript, twitter, typeahead.js

I have 2 text field , one is city , and another movie , the suggestion for movie dropdown is populated based on the city . Once the city is selected i make a ajax call to fetch the movies in the city . So now , i need to populate the source of movie field with the response . So what i tried is to use **Bloodhound.clear** to clear the values and add values from response using the **Bloodhound.add** , but it doesn't seems to work . Below is the code

```
var movies = [];
var movieEngine = new Bloodhound({
   /*initialize: false,*/
   datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
   queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
   local : movies
});

 $('#city').on('blur', function(ev) {
    if($(ev.target).val().trim() == "")
        $('#city_error').html("Please select a city");
    else{
        $('#city_error').html("");
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url:'/movie',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                'city': $('#city').val()
            }
        });
        jqxhr.done(function(data){
            movieEngine.clear();
            movieEngine.add(Object.keys(data.movieList));
            /*movies = Object.keys(data.movieList);
            movieEngine.initialize(true);*/
        });
    }
});


var movie_typeahead = $('#movie').typeahead({
    hint: false,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},{
    source: movieEngine
});
```

As you see above , i populate the suggestion for movie dropdown based on city selected , but it dosen't seems to work . I even tried another option for Bloodhound engine to initialize after i get the response **(commented lines in ajax success)**

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution but a workaround:

1. Destroy the current typeahead object. If this step is ommited, the typeahead might display two option boxes with suggestions.

   `movie_typeahead = $('#movie').typeahead('destroy');`
2. Reinitialize your Bloodhound by replacing the instance with a new one instead of using `clear()` and `initialize()`

   ```
   jqxhr.done(function(data){
         movieEngine = new Bloodhound({
             datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
             queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
             local: data.movieList
         });
   });
   ```
3. Reinitialize your typeahead object

```
    var movie_typeahead = $('#movie').typeahead({
        hint: false,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },{
        source: movieEngine
    });
```

Far from optimal but worked for me.